# how to read the serial port on SWT text widget

Tags: java, swt

I am using the javax.comm package to read some data off the serial port. 
The data is to be displayed on a SWT a text widget. I have added an 
eventListener to the serial port object and made notifyOnDataAvailable 
 true, so that my app gets notified when data arrives. Anyway, on the 
event handler, I try to append the newly read data to the text widget, 
but it does not append the read value with text widget. But when i try to print the same in console it does that perfectly. I have a similar app 
written in AWT and it doesn't have this problem. Does it have anything 
to do with the way SWT handles the main thread? Is there a way around my 
problem?

Here is my code -

```
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
    {
        try
        { 
            byte singleData = (byte)input.read();

            // READING THE SERIAL PORT VALUE HERE IN
            // TEXT AREA CALLED txtLog


            if (singleData != NEW_LINE_ASCII)
            {
                logText = new String(new byte[] {singleData});

              //  System.out.print(logText);
                txtLog.append(logText);
            }
            else
            {
              txtLog.append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logText = "Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")";
            txtLog.setForeground(Color.red);
            txtLog.append(logText + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this running in a background thread? Does the `Text` control have `SWT.MULTI` in the style?

Comment: yes. it does have SWT.MULTI in style.

Comment: @Amit.D Which thread is this code running on?

Comment: @Baz its running on main thread.

Comment: @Amit.D Try moving it to a separate thread then.

Comment: @ Baz How to keep this in separate thread? I tried all possible ways i knew. Could you suggest something or give some idea how to go about this?

Comment: @Baz Thanks. Your suggestion helped me to resolve the issue.